# Count rows inside each element of an array of buckets

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've made a query to calculate some ranges (or buckets) and now I want to count of many elements are inside in each one of them.

For example, this could be a set of rows:

| id | tx_value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 2022-03-04 |
| 2 | 0.30 | 2022-03-04 |
| 1 | 300 | 2022-03-03 |
| 4 | 3000 | 2022-03-05 |
| 5 | 30 | 2022-03-04 |

I've calculated the range with the following clause:

```
ARRAY(SELECT tx_value_range * avg_tx_value
    FROM UNNEST([0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]) AS tx_value_range) AS tx_size_buckets
```

This is a possible range:

```
[0.003, 0.03, 0.30, 3.0, 30.0, 300.0]
```

Then what I'm struggling to get is to count the amount of rows placed into each bucket, something like:

```
0.003, 3
0.03,  1
0.30,  4
```

I simply can't come up with even a test query to calculate this, I think that I'll need to iterate the bucket array for each transaction row in order to determine where to place the row but I can't seem to articulate it into a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select any_value(ranges[offset(range_pos)]) `range` , count(*) rows_count
from your_table, 
unnest([struct([0.003, 0.03, 0.30, 3.0, 30.0, 300.0] as ranges)]),
unnest([struct(range_bucket(tx_value, ranges) - 1 as range_pos)])
group by range_pos
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is it possible that the "-1" could cause an unferflow error? That's what I'm getting right now when I adapt your solution to my query.

Comment: sure. you should adjust / tune above to fit your exact logic. I would recommend just simply adding `0` to the ranges array - `[0.0, 0.003, 0.03, 0.30, 3.0, 30.0, 300.0]`